# Vue.jsのmethods内にて複数のawaitを実行すると、一つ目のawaitを実行した時点で処理が終わってしまう。

Tags: javascript, vue.js, 非同期, axios

### 発生している問題

クリックイベントで発火してAPIを二つ順番に投げる処理を書きたいのですが、以下のように実装したところ、一つ目のAPIを実行した時点で処理が終わってしまい、二つ目の API が実行されません。

async/await を利用し、順次 axios で API が実行されると期待したのですが、下記の処理では firstAPI が実行された後の処理が動きませんでした。

コンソールにも"1:firstAPI実行"だけが出力されていました。

やりたいこととしては一つ目の API でサーバー側のデータを更新し、二つ目の API で状態を取得して data を更新し、描画に反映させたいと考えております。

Vue 初心者なのですが何か間違った実装なのでしょうか・・・。

---

### 該当のソースコード

```
<template>
    <el-button　v-if="scope.row.status" @click="callAPI()" type="danger" round>連携を取り消す</el-button>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    data: () => {
        return {
          data: [],
          error: ""
        };
    },
    methods:{
        async callAPI(){
            try {
                // firstAPI
                console.log('1:firstAPI実行')
                await axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/api/first);
                console.log('2:firstAPI終了')

                // secondAPI
                console.log('3:secondAPI実行')
                const secondResult = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/second);
                console.log('4:secondAPI終了')

                this.data= secondResult.data;

            } catch (error) {
               console.log(error);
               this.error = error;
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

- "vue": "^2.5.2"
- "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
- "vuex": "^3.0.1"
- "axios":"^0.18.0"

Comment: コンソールに出力されるのが`"1:firstAPI実行"`だけということは、`axios.delete`の処理が止まっている可能性が高いと思います。呼び出されるAPI側が正常に動作しているかどうか確認したほうがよいと思います。　手始めに、デベロッパーツールでネットワークリクエストを監視し、`axios.delete`によるリクエストがどのような経過をたどっているか見てみるとよいです。